# How to log stack trace from all of the threads using ACRA

Tags: java, android, multithreading, crash-reports, acra

everybody!

Now I'm trying to use ACRA for sending crash reports on my e-mail.
I have the next ACRA settings:

```
@ReportsCrashes(
formKey = "",
mailTo = "developer@email.com",
additionalSharedPreferences = {
    CSConfig.pref.PREFERENCES
},
customReportContent = {
    ReportField.PHONE_MODEL,
    ReportField.ANDROID_VERSION,
    ReportField.APP_VERSION_NAME,
    ReportField.APP_VERSION_CODE,
    ReportField.STACK_TRACE,
    ReportField.AVAILABLE_MEM_SIZE,
    ReportField.SHARED_PREFERENCES,
    ReportField.LOGCAT
},
mode = ReportingInteractionMode.TOAST,
resToastText = R.string.crash_toast_msg
```

)

The question is: how to tell ACRA to send the stack trace from all
of the threads running (like in debug) to me?

Thanks!
I will be really appreciated for the answers!

Comment: I don't believe it is possible. May I ask why you are interested in other threads apart from the one that crashed ?

Comment: Hi! I need it to find a "race condition" problems.

Comment: maybe you could do debug it another way: by writing logs in your threads, and giving your app the READ_LOGS permission.

Comment: It's a good idea and I've already done this by adding `ReportField.LOGCAT` in `ReportCrashes`.